# Loop through char, array, do calculation for each char based on previous value Visual Basic

Tags: vba

I'm pretty new to programming but have a problem finding the answer on here to my question (I don't know exactly what to search for but know what I want if that makes sense)

In short I need to loop through a string of numbers, do calculations based on the answer of each number and store in a new variable for each answer.

```
Dim myString As String = "62835"

Dim firstNum As Integer = 39

For i = 0 To myString.Length -1

    # Here I need to use each single number of the string
    # 6 * firstNum = a
    # 2 * a = b
    # 8 * b = c
    # 3 * c = d
    # 5 * d = e

Next
```

Is there a way to loop through the numbers and store each answer in a separate string so that the output is ("a" & "b" & "c" & "d" & "e")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you can't assign values to variables while declaring them in VB. You have to assign separately.

You can use VBA functions Mid to get each character, and CLng to convert character to number. Check this code

```
Dim firstNum As Integer
firstNum = 39
Dim sNewString As String, lPrevious As String
lPrevious = CLng(Left(sNewString, 1)) * firstNum
sNewString = lPrevious
For i = 2 To Len(myString)
    sNewString = sNewString & CLng(Mid(myString, i, 1)) * lPrevious
    lPrevious = CLng(Mid(myString, i, 1))
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are approaching VBA is not the ideal. If you want to code that way I suggest you do it in Java, C#, Python, etc. In VBA the correct approach is to take advantage of the cells in the sheets.

I would code it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub loop_through()

Dim my_string As String
Dim first_multiplayer As Long
Dim first_calculation_done As Boolean
Dim pos As Byte

my_string = "62835"
first_multiplayer = 39

'convert from string to numbers and save them in a data set
For pos = 3 To Len(my_string) + 3
    Cells(pos, 3) = Mid(my_string, pos - 2, 1)
Next pos

'do a loop and store each answer in the "ANSWERS" data set
For pos = 4 To 7
    
    'a way of including the first calculation in the loop
    If first_calculation_done = False Then
    Cells(10, 3) = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.product(Cells(3, 3), first_multiplayer)
    first_calculation_done = True
    End If
    
    Cells(pos + 7, 3) = _
    WorksheetFunction.product(Cells(pos + 6, 3), Cells(4, 3))
    
Next pos

End Sub
```

Answers will be displayed like this:

[image]

In case you don't want to see the sheet you can hide it by doing left click over the sheet tab.

Give it a go...